# Whois status "pending delete" with expiration date in November 2011?

Tags: domains, domain-registrar

A friend of mine is in the process of being scammed by a domain registrar and I am trying to sort out the mess. However I could use a hand understanding some of the details.

He paid for 2 years of domain name registration on 6 november 2009.

The whois record reads:

```
Domain ID:XXXXXXXXXX
Domain Name:XXXXXXXXX.ORG
Created On:06-Nov-2009 09:23:12 UTC
Last Updated On:17-Dec-2010 00:15:10 UTC
Expiration Date:06-Nov-2011 09:23:12 UTC
Sponsoring Registrar:OnlineNIC Inc. (R64-LROR)
Status:CLIENT TRANSFER PROHIBITED
Status:HOLD
Status:PENDING DELETE SCHEDULED FOR RELEASE
Registrant ID:ONLC-XXXXXXX-X
Registrant Name:My friend's name
...
Registrant Email:Old email
```

The registrar charged a renewal fee a week ago and is now asking an extra $150 to "reclaim" the domain name, even though the domain name is apparently still in my friend's name and it looks like there is still another 10 months before the expiry date.

The expiration date on the WhoIs record looks right (Nov 2011), so I don't understand why the domain status says "PENDING DELETE SCHEDULED FOR RELEASE".

Can someone explain me better what the deal is and explain what I need to do get the domain name transfered to a more honest registrar? I already have a registrar for my own domain names, been using them for 10 years without problems, so I know where to transfer the domain names to, I just don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but would you mind naming the registrar so others can avoid this situation

Answer (score 1):

We need more information.

Did your friend buy the domain from OnlineNIC Inc or from another company that is reselling for OnlineNIC Inc. Because if it's from a reseller you can call OnlineNIC Inc and complain about that reseller and they can halp you.

Also you have a space for old email. Was the domain's who is out of date with an old email? If so that is an issue and can be used to delete the domain.